# How to open my android application to send message from Google Assistant like Whatsapp, Message and Telegram?

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, google-voice-actions, voice-interaction

I am an Android Developer.

I am developing an messaging application, which can send Text Messages and Audio Messages to other users/contacts.

I need help for below scenario.

I want to send message directly from the Google Assistant/Ok Google. like feature compatible with default Message, Whatsapp and Telegram.

When we say "Send a message to John", It opens a UI for send text message.
When we say "Send a voice message via Whatsapp", It opens a UI for send audio message.

I am working on this point last couple of days, I searched regarding Google Voice Actions, but not getting any success.

What I need to do to achieve this?

Please give your valuable suggestion.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: did you find any answer on that?

Comment: @Ajay Not found

Comment: There is any workaround?

Comment: @Nirel I did RnD workaround, but not found anything